# Eevee rendering images in a higher resolution than 1980 x 1080

Tags: rendering, resolution

I have been trying to render a JPEG image higher than my standard monitor resolution which is 1980 x 1080. I succeeded in the following resolution 5400x3600 but could not go any larger since blender crashed.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try to render it using CPU only. GPU memory size is generally smaller than CPU dual to the different spec of chips. Using GPU will potentially crash your operating system since those memory been used is not handled by system but GPU itself, and it also come with more unreliable memory guarantee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing power is limited, most computers cannot deal with that size images.

You can try adding a lot more RAM or getting a more powerful GPU (again, wtih more vRAM).

5400x3600 pixels is over 9 times larger than 1980x1080, so that will need at least 9 times more resources. Remember that increasing size means exponential increase.

If your computer cannot handle that then you have to come up with different strategies, like rendering in sections and stitch the tiles together later.

Or you can try using cloud computing or a render farm.